# Led tape connection using two power sources

Tags: led

I have two 5 meter lengths of LED RGBW tape lights running above my kitchen cupboards. They are connected to each other and are powered at either end with a 60w transformer. If I do not power one of the transformers at that end it is dimmer (not enough power) If I power all is fine. By powering both however I have to use two remotes. My question therefore is there a way to directly power one end to the strip rather than going through the remote. Thereby using one remote but two power supplies?

Thanks

Comment: How much power is this strip drawing? Also, what make/model are the power supplies?

Comment: You can't do that.  You can't have two controllers/dimmers powering the same system.  They will fight with each other, the dimming will be brighter than commanded, they will overload the power supplies, and they will tend to "shimmer" at lower brightness settings.  You can do it with one controller/dimmer powering two amplifier/boosters, one for each power supply.  The single controller will assure the boosters are pulsing in sync.  However this will only work if the controller *itself* has power.

Comment: Sounds to me like the strip is to long for the power supply, hence 2 power supplies. Not sure what the remote does, if it is just power off/on, try a switched outlet, either remote or wired. Or a different power supply that can handle the length (led count.)

Comment: @JeffCates almost surely the remote is a PWM dimmer... x2.  Which can't work.  PWM dimming isn't a buck comverter, it's literally PWM all the way out to the lamps.

Comment: I would assume dimmer capable, but they don't specify this. As for LED's, dim at one end means the power isnt making it as the first bleed off power and continue to do so down the line. If each LED has a resistor in line, this would not be a big issue, but most LED strips have a single resistor at the beginning. Each LED will drain a small amount of energy and pass what's left down the line causing subsequent diodes to not light completely.

Comment: @David Jacobs, show us some pictures. Lit, unlit, power supply connections, where the 2 strip connect, etc. Been trying to figure this one. Diodes only allow electricity to flow one direction. What's confusing is a double ended connection. One power supply shouldn't be doing anything. If both are, then one is hooked up "backwards" and in,the case, a single power supply, rated higher wattage, should do the trick.

Comment: They are all from Banggood: http://www.banggood.com/5M-RGBWWRGBW-300LEDs-SMD-5050-Non-waterproof-Flexible-LED-Strip-Light-12V24V-p-1035394.html  AND http://www.banggood.com/ARILUX-AL-LC02-Super-Mini-LED-WIFI-APP-Controller-Dimmer-for-RGBW-LED-Strip-Light-DC-9-12V-p-1060222.html Using a 60watt power supply.